# Process ID using ps aux

Tags: command-line

I'm a newbie to shell programming. Assuming that I've started a program(eg NetBeans) from my terminal, if I type

```
ps aux|grep netbeans
```

I get the the output

```
pre      18775  1.2  0.0  12524  1972 pts/3    S    20:17   0:00
```

where 18775 specifies the PID etc of the process.

Then I kill it using

```
kill 18775.
```

upon which the NetBeans UI disappears. If I try to get the pid by using the first command, I still get:

```
pre      19137  0.0  0.0   9136  1068 pts/3    S+   20:19   0:00 grep --color=auto netbeans
```

If the process has been killed, why does it still show the above output?

Comment: It's not showing you the netbeans process - it's showing the grep process through which ps aux is being piped! Since that process is `grep netbeans`, that's the program you see at the end of the line (`grep --color=auto netbeans`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

grep is grepping itself. Try something like:

```
ps aux |grep [n]etbeans
```

this keeps grep from showing itself in the output

Comment: This works, but it is not very nice. You could also do `ps aux | grep netbeans | grep -v grep`. But use pgrep instead.

Comment: @queueoverflow `pgrep` would be nice, but it only matches the process name.  The first pattern can match any column of `ps`.  (For example, something running under python or java, pgrep wouldn't be grepping the correct thing.  Same with `pkill` and so on..)

Answer (score 5):

**Never** use `ps` together with `grep`.

Rather, use `killall netbeans`, `pkill netbeans` to kill it. For the process ID `pgrep netbeans`.

More on [ps and grep](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/033).

Comment: That's the most useless advice I've ever heard. As long as people know what the grep process will look like in the output of ps (it starts with "grep") then there is absolutely no danger in using the two together.

I do understand the advice about not using a kill in a script, but that's beside the point.

Comment: And I think pgrep is worse, because it's just begging you to 'kill $(pgrep vi*)' or something amazingly unsafe like that.

Comment: This is also the most useless answer on this page, as `pgrep`, `pkill`, and so on match process name only - anything being interpreted (java, python, bash, etc...) can only be distinguished from others under the same process name by using `ps`.

Comment: @Izkata - using -f for pgrep and pkill will match against the entire command line. It's sometimes useful when trying to match stuff run under interpreters as you mention. It's also a good way to shoot yourself in the foot as it will happily kill anything that references your pattern anywhere in its command line :)

Answer (score 4):

Because that's the PID for the grep process which is queued up to run after `ps aux`.

Comment: @ovangle- *blink* I never thought of it! :D thanks!

Comment: Actually, `grep` is *already running* when `ps aux` runs. As `ps aux` runs, its output is sent to the running `grep` instance as input. If the shell hadn't executed `grep` yet, it wouldn't appear in the output of `ps`.